# Regex extract only specific character and EOL

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract some text using regex.
I want to extract only those line that contains "pour 1e" or "Pour 1€" and nothing more.
The regex must be incase-sensitive.

here is my regex that don't work like I want:

```
/Pour ([0-9.,])(€|e)/im
```

and this is my text:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica
CARDEURS
Horaire dejour de &#64258;hllll 5 19h00
pour 1€
pour 1€ supplémentaire
pour 1€ supplémentaire
pour 1€ supplémentaire
pour 1€ supplémentaire
par€ supplémentaire
Horaire de nuit de 19h00 5 &#64258;hllll
pour 1,50€
pour 1€ supplémentaire + 300 minutes
pour 1€ supplémentaire + 420 minutes
La joumée de 24 heures
35 minutes
+ 30 minutes
+ 35 minutes
+ 40 minutes
+ 45 minutes
+ 50 minutes
60 minutes
15€


Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.01 with Leptonica
TARIFS
PARKING CARNOT
Homim de juur de 8:00 3 19:00 H01-aim de null de 19:00 5 8:00
mains d‘ ggg heme : G1-atuit moins d‘ ggg heure : Gmtuil
Pour 1e
Pour 1e supplémenlaire
Pour 1e suppléulentaire
Pour 1e supplémmmm
Pour 1e supplémmmm
Par e supplémenlaiI€
40 minutes
+ 40 minutes
+ 45 minutes
+ 50 minutes
+ 55 minutes
+ 55 minules
Pour 1e so nzinules
Pour 1e supplémenlaiI€ + 300 minllles
Pour 1e 5upplémenlai1Q + 420 minules
La journée a
e 24 heums 15€
```

Comment: Do or don't you want to match `pour 2€` or `pour 1,50e`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "nothing more"? "Contains" implies that there may be other content on that line. Or did you mean "consists of"?

Comment: **Pour 1e** this is good one.
**Pour 1e supplémenlaire** this is not good. @Tim Peitzcker I want every float number, not just 1.

Comment: Do you have the whole text in a single variable and are matching the regex against this very variable? Or are you matching the regex against each line of the text?

Answer (score 2):

You need to anchor the expression with `^` and `$` which match beginning/end of line when `/m` is active. For example:

```
/^pour [0-9]+[0-9,.]*[e€]$/im
```

Comment: dont work. If I remove $ at the end, matches all lines starting with pour, not only those that end with e|€

Comment: @user2655799: Sure, that's why you mustn't remove the `$`. According to your comment to your question, this is the answer you need.

Comment: but if I dont remove $ the regex match nothing.

Answer (score 1):

use square brackets `[]` to specify a group of characters to match, caret `^` to match the beginning of the line and dollar sign `$` to match the end of the line.  Depending on which regex implementation you are using you may be able to pass the `i` flag to make it case-insensitive

```
/^Pour 1[€e]$/i
```

Or handle case explicitly with character groups

```
/^[Pp][Oo][Uu][Rr] 1[€e]$/
```

For matching repetitions, use `*` to match 0 or more of the previous character, `+` to match 1 or more, and `?` to match 0 or 1.

In place of the 1 in the previous, you could use

```
[0-9.]+ to match any 1 or more digits or decimal points
[0-9]+\.?[0-9]* to match at least 1 digit follow by an optional decimal point and more digits
[0-9]+[0-9,]*\.?[0-9]* to match at least 1 digit, optionally more digits and commas, followed by an optional decimal point and more digits
```

You can also use curly braces `{}` to explicitly specify a number of repetitions (these must be escaped with a backslash `\` in some regex engines)

```
[0-9]{1,3} would match 1,2 or 3 digits
[0-9]{3} would match exactly 3 digits
```

You can use parenthesis `()` to group a part of a regex pattern for backreference or repetition.

So to match a line that starts with "Pour " followed by 1 or more digits, then an optional comma or decimal point with 2 digits, then the euro symbol or letter e, and any number of trailing spaces, but no other characters until end of line, and be case-insensitive:

```
/^Pour [0-9]+([,.][0-9][0-9])?[€e][ ]*$/i
```